# Laravel 5 Sending email to owner after a user register

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using the default login and registration system of Laravel. I just want to do whenever a new user was successfully registered an email will be sent to one of the email address that I will input, like sending an email to me to notify me that a new user register.

How will I do this?

Comment: Which exact Laravel version You are using?

Comment: The Laravel version is 5.2

Comment: You can accomplish that using Events & Listeners. Check here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply overwrite `register` method in `AuthController`.

Put something like this and it will send super simple email to registered user:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // original script, do not touch it
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    \Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));

    // Your custom script
    \Mail::raw('Welcome ' . $request->input('name') . '!', function ($m) use ($request) {
        $m->to($request->input('email'))->subject('Registration successful!');
    });

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

To learn more about mailing, You should read official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Comment: Will i just copy this to the AuthController? Sorry im still noob in Laravel and im just starting to use this.

Comment: @Ace Yes, just copy paste this method to `AuthController` and it will send simply email to registered person. If You want to email Yourself when someone registers - change receiver in `$m->to(<receiver>)`.

Comment: How do i input a email address in the $m->to(<receiver>), how will i write it? when i tried chainging the $m->to($request->input('email') it errors.

Comment: it shows an error. ReflectionException in Route.php line 286:
Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request does not exist.

Comment: @Ace You have to import `Request` :) Place `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in Your import section.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot about that. Thanks! Its working now. :)

Comment: oh 1 more question, how do i put multiple email in @m->to(<reciever>)?

Comment: @Ace You can pass array of emails, like so `$m->to(['first@email.com', 'second@email.com'])`

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help! :)